# create multiple aliases for same class | PHP

Tags: php

I need to create multiple aliases for one same class, and select the another database based on the actual alias name:

EXAMPLE:

```
$q = DB::query(...);
```

alias DB2, DB3 for class "DB":

```
$q = DB2::query(...);
$q = DB3::query(...);
```

Is there any solution? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: [`class_alias()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php) ?

Comment: Must have searched hard on google for this.

Comment: I found another solution yet - class DB2 extends DB {};

Answer (score 2):

There is a function [class_alias()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php) in PHP for this.

```
class_alias('DB', 'DB2');
class_alias('DB', 'DB3');
```

Also, you can just extend it:

```
class DB2 extends DB {}
class DB3 extends DB {}
```

Comment: Extending a class should, ideally, only be done if it actually is an *extension* of the parent class (i.e. adds to/modifies it in some way). What the questioner seems to be asking is to only *alias* the class, i.e. be able to use the class under a different name. Good answer, though. +1

Comment: Yes, but this a possibility too :-) I find the first method better too :-)

Comment: @JohnJohnm1: That makes no sense. In object context, `get_class()` and `get_class($this)` should be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

First I need to make connection to the database based on the current alias name. Is this good solution for good memory performance?

MY CODE:

```
<?php
class DB 
{
    public static function query($id)
    {
        //query ....

        $class = static::getClass();
        return new $class;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo get_class($this); //select database by class name
    }
}

class DB2 extends DB
{
    public static function getClass()
    {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}

class DB3 extends DB
{
    public static function getClass()
    {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}

$q = DB2::query(1);
$q = DB3::query(1);
?>
```